# node.js recommendation engine with weight support

Tags: node.js, redis, recommendation-engine, weighted

I'm researching for a while to find a recommendation engine for an upcoming nodejs project where i have do return recommendations based on weighted likes. As my dataset will become quiet large database support is essential for me.

So far i've found [recommendationRaccoon](https://github.com/guymorita/recommendationRaccoon) which has redis support (yeah!) but doesn't support weigths for events as it's using [`sadd`](https://github.com/guymorita/recommendationRaccoon/blob/master/lib/input.js#L33) under the hood.

I've also found [ger](https://github.com/grahamjenson/ger) and it's `view` action in the readme (maybe use multiple views to weight my actions) but the code [just updates the dates](https://github.com/grahamjenson/ger/blob/master/lib/basic_in_memory_esm.coffee#L236) and doesn't insert the new event.

Do you have any suggestions for a recommendation engine that fits my needs?

Thanks in advance!